# Quadric surface doubt related to cylinder.

Tags: analytic-geometry, quadrics

I was trying to figure out the solution for a problem then I encountered a doubt.
First of all, here is the question for **clarity**:

*Show that $2x^2+5y^2+4xy+2yz-4zx+16x+22y-10z-18=0$ is the equation of the cylinder which passes through the point $(3,-1,1)$ and has the axis $\frac{x-1}{2}=\frac{y+3}{-1}=\frac{z-2}{1}$*.

My Approach:

Now, I checked, whether $(3,-1,1)$ satifies the equation of the given cylinder, and yes it satifies (first part done), now I have to prove that $\frac{x-1}{2}=\frac{y+3}{-1}=\frac{z-2}{1}$ is the equation of the axis of the given cylinder.

We know, a generator lying on the cylinder will have the same dr's as the axis (as they are both parallel lines), and we can assume that generator line to pass through $(3,-1,1)$, and hence, the equation of that generator line will be:

$\frac{x-3}{2}=\frac{y+1}{-1}=\frac{z-1}{1}=r$.

Now, any general point of the above generating line goes this way:

$x=2r+3, y=-r-1, z=r+1$.

Now, since, the generating line lies on the cylinder, each and every general point of the generating line must satisfy the equation of the cylinder. I tried substituting the general point coordinates, i.e., ($x=2r+3, y=-r-1, z=r+1$) in the given equation of the cylinder.

Then I found out:

i) coefficient of $r^2$ and $r$ is equal to 0.

ii) $LHS\neq0(RHS)$

Now, "coefficient of $r^2$ and $r$ is equal to 0" would directly mean that the generator line *fully lies* on the cylinder (thus increasing the probability that given axial equation is the equation of the given cylinder), but " $LHS\neq0(RHS)$ " would tell me that each and every point of the generator line is not satisfying the equation of the cylinder. Thus, because of this problem I am not able to solve this problem.

What should I do? Is my thought process/approach correct? How to prove that the given axial line equation is the equation of the given cylinder?

Comment: Why would a point on a cylinder also be on its axis??

Comment: The original equation isn’t that of a cylinder in the first place. Check for transcription errors.

Comment: Is the equation of the cylinder correct? I found $-5r^2$ and $-10r.$